# Providing a huge amount of data between activities, searching for best solution

Tags: android, file, android-activity, large-data

I am building an app with a huge amount of data and I need a good solution to deal with this problem. I have a class which represents a data set. it contains several ArrayLists and some simple data types. I want to save a lot of these classes in an ArrayList into a file. When I start the app the data should be loaded and every activity should use these data. how can I share these data between my different activities?

Comment: Use SQLLite if it all can remain local, otherwise farm it out to AWS (SimpleDB perhaps) if you want to share the data across devices. In addition, if you can clarify what constitutes _huge_ that may help others provide a best approach.

Answer (score 0):

When your first activity starts that time use the **AsyncTask** and load all the data from your data base or where you placed in app and set it to model classes. Make the model classes public and also all variables and methods too. so that all activities of app can use that data. The example is here.

```
/* Calling a LoadDataBase() class extending AsyncTask 
* to run in background for creating or loading data base.
*/
new LoadDataBase().execute();
```

Than code this AsyncTask class as:

```
// LoadDataBase class for background execution.
private class LoadDataBase extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{  
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // DataBaseHelper class object.
    DataBaseHelperClass dbHelper = new DataBaseHelperClass(this);
    // Create database for the first time.
    try {
    dbHelper.createOrLoadDataBase();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    // Closing the database connection.
        dbHelper.close();
    return "";
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
//Your code to set data loaded from database to model classes by using getter
    //setter methods.       
} // end onPostExecute(Void... values).
} // LoadDataBase.
```

May this will help you.